# How come the node models folders is so big if the end user doesn't get all that anyway?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, node-modules

When I check the size of my node models folder its about 350 MB. It's not suce a a big project, so 
I assume this is pretty standard? Obviously the user doesn't need to download 350 MB when visiting my site. So why does it need to exist on my disk?

Comment: I had the same question, so I investigated and found that some packages depend on big dependencies, like Puppeteer or Selenium, they have headless browser for test their packages while developing and they put these on dependencies instead of dev-dependencies. You are right, some of them, you do not need them at all.

Comment: A lot of the dependencies will only be required for building your packages. For example if you’re using a build tool such as Webpack with Eslint, those will not end up in your final bundles in the browser.